# How to pause Windows TIMEOUT command?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I use

```
TIMEOUT /T 10
```

in a batch file to keep its window open so that I can read some output. Most of the time, I'm happy for it to close in 10 seconds. Sometimes I want to close it immediately and press a key. Very occasionally I want more time to read it. Is there a key I can press to pause the countdown until I press the same or another key? Either the countdown continuing or the window closing is fine.

```
PAUSE
```

or

```
TIMEOUT /T -1
```

are not acceptable as they don't have the auto-closing behavior.

Comment: I checked timeout.exe in a debugger. It ignores focus events and CTRL and ALT key presses when it comes to updating the message, but otherwise it doesn't look for any key combination to pause the timer.  Suspending the process doesn't help either because it computes the remaining time from a deadline time and the current time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PING` command can be used to [simulate `TIMEOUT`](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.msdos.batch.nt/nSRpfQE-lko/WEWG9aCfSoAJ). To sleep for 10 seconds:

```
PING -n 11 127.0.0.1 > NUL
```

To pause sleeping, you would hit <kbd>Break</kbd>. Then, to unpause and continue sleeping you would hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, I found that pressing Space or Enter also unpauses. To hide the output messages and make it easier to remember and type, I decided on `ping -n 11 localhost>NUL`